# Question about Lagrange Duality and saddle points

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

Consider two Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ and an extended real valued function $f:\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ with $f\in\Gamma_0(\mathcal{H})$ the set of proper, lower semicontinuous, convex functions. We look at the following problem (we will refer to this as the primal),

$$\min f(x) : Ax=0$$

where $A:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{G}$ is a linear operator.

We can form the classical Lagrangian for our problem,

$$\mathcal{L}(x,\mu) = f(x) + \langle \mu, Ax\rangle$$

and state the dual problem,

$$\max_\mu\min_x\mathcal{L}(x,\mu)$$

Let us also assume that strong duality holds. My question, then, is the following:

Imagine you have a particular solution $\bar{\mu}$ to the dual problem and you also have a solution $x^*\in\arg\min\limits_{x}\mathcal{L}(x,\bar{\mu})$. Is it true that $Ax^*=0$, i.e. $x^*$ is feasible and thus $(x^*,\bar{\mu})$ is a saddle point/primal dual pair?

Comment: If $x^*$ is a unique minimizer of $L(x,\bar\mu)$ then yes, otherwise no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Take $\min_{x} \{ x : x = 0 \}$. The Lagrangian is $L(x,\mu)=x+\mu x$, the unique saddle point is $(x,\mu)=(0,-1)$, while any $x$ minimizes the Lagrangian.

Comment: I was just about to post the example $\min x\colon x=0$ :)

Comment: @A.Γ. that is actually a better example because the rhs in the question is 0.